# Unit test SessionScoped class

Tags: guice

I'm using Guice 4 and I have a class that I want to be scoped at the http session level, so I've decorated it with **@SessionScoped**. The issue is, when I unit test this class I get the following exception. I don't know how should I emulate this in my test.

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No scope is bound to com.google.inject.servlet.SessionScoped.
  at org.abc.collab.repo.SessionedUOW.class(SessionedUOW.java:12)
  at org.abc.business.BusinessModule.configure(BusinessModule.java:18)
```

Comment: Post your test example, the minimum necessary, including your guice test module.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using Guice only partially: You have your class hooked up, but not the scope binding (call to [`bindScope`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#bindScope-java.lang.Class-com.google.inject.Scope-)) that it needs.

In general, you should not be using a real Guice injector in a unit test; instead, instantiate your class using its constructor and provide its dependencies yourself (using fakes or mocks as needed).

If you do need to use Guice, be forewarned that this is no longer a *unit test* and is now much more like a *system test* or *integration test*. At that point, you'll need to diagnose which call to `bindScope` you need, and consider extracting it into a test helper to make the rest of your testing easier.